# Not Like Wildcard select query not working in MS Access

Tags: database, csv, ms-access, select, insert

I'm importing data from CSV to Access Database. When I'm using `"Not Like"` to filter some values from a column I am getting an incorrect result.

Inserting data from CSV (ANSI) to Access (Office 16) and when I put `Not Like '%HELLO%'` the result contains `"HELLO"`.

- Column of Database: `ID`, `Task`, `Remarks`, `Date`
- Column of CSV: `ID #`, `Task`,`Remarks`, `Date`

Since there is a space in the CSV header I am using square brackets.

```
INSERT INTO table_Name ( ID, Task, Remarks, Date) 
SELECT [ID #], [Task ], [Remarks ], [Date ]
FROM [Text;FMT=CSVDelimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=C:\Log].[Ext#csv] Where [Remarks ] not like '%HELLO%' ;
```

I expect the query should insert data for which the `"Remarks"` column in the CSV does **not** contain `"HELLO"`. But I am actually getting the data with `"HELLO"`.

Comment: Not Alike also does not worked .
I tried using below methods:
Not [Remarks ] Like '%HELLO%'
 [Remarks ] Not Like '%HELLO%'
 [Remarks ] Not alike '%HELLO%'

None of these methods works properly

Answer (score 0):

By default, MS Access uses the asterisk `*` as the [wildcard operator](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931) to match any character or set of characters (not the percent symbol `%` as used by RDBMS such as SQL Server and others).

You will also need to surround your `Date` field with square brackets in your `insert into` statement (i.e. `[Date]`), as this is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2) in MS Access.

Comment: I tried with * (asterik) as well it gives the same result